# Install older version of firefox for SlimerJS

Tags: command-line, software-installation, firefox, javascript, npm

I need some help with installation of firefox older version. Also I have to make it work with SlimerJS npm module. As it says on [SlimerJS website](https://slimerjs.org/download.html) it works with versions of firefox from 38.0 to 52.0.
So, this is my steps:

1. Download an archive from mozilla cdn

   ```
   wget -c https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/51.0b9/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-51.0b9.tar.bz2`
   ```
2. Extract this archive

   ```
   tar xjf firefox-51.0b9.tar.bz2
   ```
3. Configure SlimerJS as [the docs say](https://docs.slimerjs.org/current/installation.html#configuring-slimerjs)

   ```
   export SLIMERJSLAUNCHER=/usr/bin/firefox
   ```
4. Run my testing script (just simple `console.log("Hello Slimer!");`)

   ```
   slimerjs test-1.js --debug=true
   ```

As a result I have this in my terminal:

```
Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays
Gecko error: it seems /usr/bin/firefox is not compatible with SlimerJS.
See Gecko version compatibility. If version is correct, launch slimerjs
with --debug=true to see Firefox error message
```

May be I'm doing something wrong? Please help me If someone has an idea. I really want to make this stuff working.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution for same this error :

> Error: Platform version '5x.xx' is not compatible with  or  Gecko
>   error: it seems /usr/bin/firefox is not compatible with SlimerJS.
>   See Gecko version compatibility. If version is correct, launch
>   slimerjs
>   with --debug=true to see Firefox error message

is use old firefox version inside your updated firefox:

1. update `SlimerJS` and make sure this the latest version.
2. Download the mozilla firefox version 50 from :
   https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/50.0/ and choose your OS and i386 or x64 and favorite lang for example i download `https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/50.0/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-50.0.tar.bz2` for `Ubuntu 16.04 64bit`
3. then extract the downloaded file:

   $ tar xvjf firefox-50.0.tar.bz2

for example i extract into `/home/username/oldmozilla`

4. set extracted directory to SLIMERJSLAUNCHER path:

   $ export SLIMERJSLAUNCHER=/home/yourname/oldmozilla/firefox/firefox

> note: you must give firefox app not directory

5. run your js app simply ; )